# How can I find out user's google play country?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

In my app I have in app billing support, since there is no API to get the price of an item before actually showing the user the buy UI, I am currently thinking on hard coding the price for the in app billing items inside the app.

However the pricing would be different depending on the country, so I would need to find a way to know the country the user is on to show the right price in the app.

I've found that the price the user is shown depends on the country the user selected when creating the Google Play account, so I will need a way to know the country associated to the user's google play account. Does anyone know how to do this?

thanks

Comment: Have you looked into this: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/CountrySpecification.html

Comment: @Clay I think this is no longer necessary since they added the ability to get the price of an item in V3 of the api https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getSkuDetails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SkuDetails](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/browse/v3/src/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util/SkuDetails.java?r=ba61fb3aaad43650b1f0e73d6057d5374ff43518) object and getter for price, it will return you localized price for an item.

1. Get `Inventory` object
2. get SKU detail from it :

   userInventory.getSkuDetails(IabHelper.YOUR_SKU).getPrice();

More info here - http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html

Comment: But actually this does return the localized price but not the country, e.g. in europe are a lot of countries where the currency is EUR. How could I find out from which country the purchaser comes from?

Comment: you probably can't because it's by design. User can be in the US but using other's country payments method, so assuming country and showing prices based on country would be incorrect I think